# Como fazer vários prints na mesma linha em python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quero saber como fazer para os prints serem apresentados na mesma linha usando python 3. Exemplo:

```
print('1')
print('2')
1
2
```

eu queria que quando o python fosse printar o número 2, o número um fosse apagado e o 2 aparecesse na mesma linha em que o 1 estava antes.

tentei fazer com um código disponibilizado em outra pergunta aqui mesmo, mas nao obtive o resultado esperado.

```
import sys
import time

for x in range(11):
  print("{}%".format (x))
  sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
  time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Por favor. não poste seus códigos como imagem. Como viu nas outras perguntas e respostas, o site possui suporte a códigos fonte. Para mais informações, faça o [tour], leia o guia de [ask] e acesse a [help].

Comment: E, por favor, verifique se o seu terminal possui suporte para tais caracteres. O mesmo código que copiou da outra pergunta funcionou perfeitamente aqui: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ac7kw.gif

Answer (score 5):

Python 3 automaticamente coloca uma quebra de linha no final do `print`, mas você pode sobrescrever com o que você quiser que seja adicionando o parâmetro `end`:

```
print('1', end='') 
print('2')
```

Dessa forma o `print` irá terminar com uma *string* vazia ao invés de uma quebra de linha e o segundo `print` será renderizado logo em seguida.

Comment: existe algum parametro do end que apague o que foi printado anteriormente?

Comment: Edição revertida pois o novo texto alterava a resposta. Claramente é dito que é possível passar qualquer valor como `end` na função `print` e posteriormente comentado que com o caractere vazio a saída será na mesma linha. A edição reduzia as informações da resposta e adicionava redundância.